# Javascript - convert integer to array of bits

Tags: javascript, integer, bit

I am trying in javascript to convert an integer (which I know will be between 0 and 32), to an array of 0s and 1s. I have looked around but couldn't find something that works..

So, if I have an integer as 22 (binary 10110), I would like to access it as:

```
Bitarr[0] = 0
Bitarr[1] = 1
Bitarr[2] = 1
Bitarr[3] = 0
Bitarr[4] = 1
```

Any suggestions? 
Many thanks

Comment: An array of bits it not a byte. And an array of 0's and 1's is probably just an array of int.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

convert to base 2:

```
var base2 = (yourNumber).toString(2);
```

access the characters (bits):

```
base2[0], base2[1], base2[3], etc...
```

Comment: Fantastic, this works so well! I was looking at bit-shift operations for ages but this is much faster. Many thanks!!

Comment: U wrote "array of bits", so ---> var base2 = (yourNumber).toString(2).split(''); <--- will give you each character (string, you still have to parseInt) within an array.

Comment: What does wrapping _yourNumber_ in parentheses do?  If I run `var base2 = 5.toString(2);` it won't work, so I'm curious...  Thanks!

Comment: Of all the complicated ways to figure out the value of a bit in a byte, this is by far the simplest! Thanks :)

Comment: if you have integer literal, e,g you can `21..toString(2)`. No need to convert to Number object.

Comment: It should be noted that the resulting string is **not** padded with leading zeros. If you wanted an 8-bit string with leading zeros you could use `("00000000" + number.toString(2)).slice(-8)`, for example.

Comment: The original question requests a right-to-left parsing of the split string:  
`var base2 = (yourNumber).toString(2).reverse()`

Comment: This helped me with the BinaryGap test in Codility. Thank you so much ♥!

Answer (score 14):

## Short (ES6)

Shortest (32 chars) version which fill last bits by zero. I assume that `n` is your number, `b` is base (number of output bits):

```
[...Array(b)].map((x,i)=>n>>i&1)
```

```js
let bits = (n,b=32) => [...Array(b)].map((x,i)=>(n>>i)&1);

let Bitarr = bits(22,8);

console.log(Bitarr[0]); // = 0
console.log(Bitarr[1]); // = 1
console.log(Bitarr[2]); // = 1
console.log(Bitarr[3]); // = 0
console.log(Bitarr[4]); // = 1
```

Answer (score 10):

```
var a = 22;
var b = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  b[i] = (a >> i) & 1;

alert(b);
```

Assuming 5 bits (it seemed from your question), so `0 <= a < 32`. If you like you can make the `5` larger, upto `32` (bitshifting in JavaScript works with 32 bit integer).

Answer (score 3):

This should do

```
for(int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
  Bitarr[i] = (my_int >> i) & 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your integer to a binary String like this. Note the base 2 parameter.

```
var i = 20;
var str = i.toString(2); // 10100
```

You can access chars in a String as if it were an array:

```
alert(str[0]); // 1
alert(str[1]); // 0
etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

Building up on previous answers: you may want your array to be an array of integers, not strings, so here is a one-liner:

```
(1234).toString(2).split('').map(function(s) { return parseInt(s); });
```

Note, that shorter version, `(11).toString(2).split('').map(parseInt)` will not work (chrome), for unknown to me reason it converts `"0"`s to `NaN`s

Comment: `map(parseInt)` doesn't work, for `Array.prototype.map(`) provides 3 args for its callback, of which the 2nd is the array _index_. `parseInt()` expects 2 args, of which the 2nd is the _radix_.

Comment: ```(11).toString(2).split('').map(val=>parseInt(val))```

Comment: I just used the @HJCross code to create an array of bitmask values from a number:  
`(11).toString(2).split("").reverse().map((v, i) => (parseInt(v) ? Math.pow(2, i) : 0)).filter(v => v != 0)` returns [1, 2, 8].  There doesn't seem to be a way to format code nicely in comments here.  Am I missing something?

Comment: bits as bools version: `(2).toString(2).padStart(8,0).split('').map(function(x){return (x == 1)})` with padding

Answer (score 1):

In addition, this code gives 32length array

```
function get_bits(value){
        var base2_ = (value).toString(2).split("").reverse().join("");
        var baseL_ = new Array(32 - base2_.length).join("0");
        var base2 = base2_ + baseL_;
        return base2;
    }
1 => 1000000000000000000000000000000
2 => 0100000000000000000000000000000
3 => 1100000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: This gives strings of length 31. The third line should be:  

     var baseL_ = new Array(33 - base2_.length).join("0");

Answer (score 1):

You might do as follows;

```js
var n = 1071,
    b = Array(Math.floor(Math.log2(n))+1).fill()
                                         .map((_,i,a) => n >> a.length-1-i & 1);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work for numbers bigger than 32 bits, due to the bitwise operations

Answer (score 1):

just for the sake of refernce:

```js
(121231241).toString(2).split('').reverse().map((x, index) => x === '1' ? 1 << index : 0).reverse().filter(x => x > 0).join(' + ');
```

would give you:

```
67108864 + 33554432 + 16777216 + 2097152 + 1048576 + 524288 + 65536 + 32768 + 16384 + 4096 + 1024 + 512 + 256 + 128 + 8 + 1
```