# What does ~[Array].indexOf(key) do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, operators, bit-manipulation

I'm using and adapting the [MVC example](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/mvc) included in the Express.js repository.

In one of the modules, there's a JavaScript construct I'm not familiar with. The intent is to iterate through keys on an object and skip a few that are "reserved", but I don't understand what is happening with the ***tilde*** from a JavaScript perspective.

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (~['name', 'prefix', 'engine', 'before'].indexOf(key)) continue; 
}
```

**I'm reading it's a Bitwise NOT operator, but would appreciate an explanation in layman's terms of what that means, as well as what it's doing in this particular example.**

Comment: Basically `~-1==0`, and zero is falsy.

Comment: If key is not found in the array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indexOf` returns `-1` if not found. `~-1` is `0`, i.e. `false`. So the whole things means: if `key` **is found** in the array, do continue.

Comment: Can you add some color as to why ~-1 is 0? I am trying to read up on this, but not clear on how negative numbers are treated. Is `~-X==0`  ?

Comment: @JDMaresco: `NOT x = −x − 1`, ie `-(-1)-1 == 0`

Comment: `-1` is a signed integer composed of 32 bits. Each of them is one. Bitwise negation turns each of them to zero. An integer of all zeros is zero. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9954783/328977, assign `my_int = -1` and try yourself.

Comment: It's quite the opposite: the whole thing means that if `key` is found in the array, continue.

Comment: @aduch: You are right! I'll fix the answer. Thanks!