# How to create a binary string from an array in the browser?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, browser, binary

I want to send the data captured from my microphone (converted to unsigned 16bit integers) in the browser to my server as a binary string, but I'm having a hard time doing that.

I tried using `String.fromCodePoint` on my array, but it seems that the resulting String is not a valid one. I also tried using `DataView`, but not sure how to get a binary String out of that either.

Does anyone know how that can be achieved?

EDIT: I am referring to binary data, as is "binary file", and not to "binary representation of an integer".

Answer (score 0):

This did not answer the question.
<strike>If only in the browser you can use the `btoa` function to encode to a base64 string.</strike>

Edit:
I am assuming you have an array of integers.

Final Edit:
Maybe try something like:

```
arr.map(function(item) {    
    var value = item.toString(2);    
    var padLength = 16 - value.length;    
    var binaryVal = "0".repeat(padLength) + value;

    return binaryVal;
}).join("");
```

Comment: I have an array of unsigned 16bit integers (0 to 65535), `btoa` creates base64 encoded string from other string. Also, is it necessary to do base64? I'm handling raw binary in the server side anyway?

Comment: You can pass an array (or at least I was able to in my testing). It isn't difficult to decode a base64 string on the server, but the decoded string would look something like `"1,2,3,4,5"` so it would also require some string splitting which might not work well for your situation. Especially if the array size is very large.

Comment: Maybe look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954757/javascript-convert-integer-to-array-of-bits) and see if it works for you?

Comment: having array printed to string is not what I want. the answer you're referring to is about converting an integer to it's base 2 representation, so it's something else. thanks for your effort, though!

Comment: I updated my answer as I now understand your question